# I have an unindentation error that I can't figure out how to fix

Tags: python

I am currently doing [an assignment for the MIT introduction to python](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf), part C. I keep on getting:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Here is the code:

```
#MIT C
# setting up varaibles
interest = float(0.04)
semi_annual_raise = float(0.07)
total_cost=1000000
portion_down_payment=0.25
downpayment=total_cost*portion_down_payment
starting_annual_salary=float(input("Enter the starting salary: "))
monthly_salary=starting_annual_salary/12
current_savings = 0
# setting up guess
programe = 1 
low=0
high = 1
step = 0
month = 1
guess = (high+low)/2.0
tolerance=500
savings = 0
# semi annual raise code
while programe == 1:
        end_salary = (monthly_salary * 36) * (interest * 3)
        current_savings = guess * end_salary
        savings = guess * end_salary
        if current_savings >  downpayment +- tolerance:
             print("the savings rate was too high ," , guess)
             print("reunning program")
             low = guess
             guess = (high + low) / 2.0
             current_savings = guess * end_salary
             savings = guess * end_salary
        elif current_savings < downpayment +- tolerance:
             print("the savings rate was too low ," , guess)
             print("rerunning program")
             high = guess
             guess = (high+low)/2.0
             current_savings = guess * end_salary
             savings = guess * end_salary
         else savings == downpayment +- tolerance:
             print("enter starting salary: " , starting_annual_salary)
             print("best savings rate:" , guess)
             print("steps in bisection search" , step)
             programe = 0.5
        continue
    if programe == 0.5:
        break all
```

Comment: Your statements inside the if/elif/else are all 5 spaces in. It should be 4 spaces. 4 spaces = 1 tab. Also, your actual else statement is spaced in by 1 compared to your if and elif.

Comment: Your `else` is not lined up correctly. The error message told you exactly where the problem was.

Comment: By the way, `+- tolerance` means "plus negative tolerance", which is equivalent to just `-tolerance`. I don't think it's doing what you want it to do.

Comment: This is really just a typo and should be closed as such. I don't think that this is useful to anyone other than OP

Comment: Your else savings == downpayment +- tolerance: 'must be either an 'else:' or an 'elif ....'.. Because of the comparison I guess it must be an 'elif'.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many spaces there are (at least from the point of view of the interpreter). The problem is that the `if` at the end is not at the same indentation level as the

Comment: allright so the comment of khelwood is saying +) doesn't mean anything. I was going for a if saving isnt in the downpayment within the tolrence of the price of 500 then run all the code, is there a function or a symbol that does this? thanks

Comment: "I can't figure out how to fix" - Step 1: read the error message, in order to understand which line Python thinks is misaligned. Step 2: say, out loud, exactly how many spaces you think should be in front of that line, and your clear reasoning for why. Step 3: notice that what you are saying either does not make sense, or else argues for something different from what the code actually says.

Comment: Aside from that, there is no such thing as `break all` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code a bit so it will run without error messages:

```py
#MIT C
# setting up varaibles
interest = float(0.04)
semi_annual_raise = float(0.07)
total_cost=1000000
portion_down_payment=0.25
downpayment=total_cost*portion_down_payment
starting_annual_salary=float(input("Enter the starting salary: "))
monthly_salary=starting_annual_salary/12
current_savings = 0
# setting up guess
programe = 1 
low=0
high = 1
step = 0
month = 1
guess = (high+low)/2.0
tolerance=500
savings = 0
# semi annual raise code
while programe == 1:
    end_salary = (monthly_salary * 36) * (interest * 3)
    current_savings = guess * end_salary
    savings = guess * end_salary
    if current_savings >  downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("the savings rate was too high ," , guess)
        print("reunning program")
        low = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2.0
        current_savings = guess * end_salary
        savings = guess * end_salary
    elif current_savings < downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("the savings rate was too low ," , guess)
        print("rerunning program")
        high = guess
        guess = (high+low)/2.0
        current_savings = guess * end_salary
        savings = guess * end_salary
    elif savings == downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("enter starting salary: " , starting_annual_salary)
        print("best savings rate:" , guess)
        print("steps in bisection search" , step)
        programe = 0.5
    continue
    if programe == 0.5:
        break
```

However, I think it is stuck in an ongoing loop. I am not sure what exactly you want the program to do, so I could not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything from the start of `end_salary` to the `continue` statement has been indented with 8 spaces, instead of 4.

It also looks like all of the lines under each `if` statement are indented with 5 spaces instead of 4.

Try pulling those back and you should see the error go away.

Here's my sanitized code:

```
#MIT C
# setting up varaibles
interest = float(0.04)
semi_annual_raise = float(0.07)
total_cost=1000000
portion_down_payment=0.25
downpayment=total_cost*portion_down_payment
starting_annual_salary=float(input("Enter the starting salary: "))
monthly_salary=starting_annual_salary/12
current_savings = 0
# setting up guess
programe = 1 
low=0
high = 1
step = 0
month = 1
guess = (high+low)/2.0
tolerance=500
savings = 0
# semi annual raise code
while programe == 1:
    end_salary = (monthly_salary * 36) * (interest * 3)
    current_savings = guess * end_salary
    savings = guess * end_salary
    if current_savings >  downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("the savings rate was too high ," , guess)
        print("reunning program")
        low = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2.0
        current_savings = guess * end_salary
        savings = guess * end_salary
    elif current_savings < downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("the savings rate was too low ," , guess)
        print("rerunning program")
        high = guess
        guess = (high+low)/2.0
        current_savings = guess * end_salary
        savings = guess * end_salary
    else savings == downpayment +- tolerance:
        print("enter starting salary: " , starting_annual_salary)
        print("best savings rate:" , guess)
        print("steps in bisection search" , step)
        programe = 0.5
    continue
    if programe == 0.5:
        break all
```

Comment: WOW that was a quick, normaly on forums i have to wait like an hour to get a response so thanks, I have readjusted the indents level of my code to use 4 spaces, however now My code is stuck in a infinite loop because the bissection search is not resseting the guess and just rewriting the rate was too low over and over. I know this is a lot to ask but can one of you tell me how i screwed up the bissection search code? thanks